# Why shutdownNow() method is able to break for-loop inside Callable object, but fails to do so inside Runnable, unless we specifically call break?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have this code snippet that runs a single thread executor with two tasks of either Callable, or Runnable type. Both tasks run a simple for-loop counter with `Thread.sleep()` delay per iteration. The second task starts off immediately after the first task is finished. The `awaitTermination()` method is supposed to shutdown executor before it manages to complete.

I understand that `shutdownNow()` calls `interrupt()` to a currently executing task as soon as time elapses in `awaitTermination()`, somehow managing to immediately break the for-loop inside the first task and aborting the second task if the type of object is `MyCallableTask`. Now, if I change the type of submitted objects to `MyRunnableTask` the code will also terminate the for-loop as expected, but only because I've included `break` in the try-catch block when calling `Thread.sleep()`.

```java
@Override public void run() {
    for (int j = 0; j < forLoops; j++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If there was no break, the code would have finished the for-loop first and then stop.

My question is why don't we need to include any breaks or returns in `call()` implementation of `MyCallableTask`? I mean, how come the code succeeds to immediately break the for-loop in the `call()` method without any additional instructions?

```java
@Override public Void call() throws Exception {
    for (int j = 0; j < forLoops; j++) {
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`InterruptedException` is a checked exception.

You either have to handle it inside the method (with a try/catch), or declare that the method throws it (or a superclass).

Runnable implementations can't throw checked exceptions like `InterruptedException` (its base declaration doesn't have `throws Exception` or `throws InterruptedException`); `Callable` can, because its declaration does.

---

Btw, your `Runnable` case should call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` before the break, so that anything which called that Runnable can also know it was interrupted.

You also don't really need the break of you put the try/catch around the loop instead of inside it.

Comment: @Any Turner I wondered what interrupts `Thread.sleep()` and for-loop inside `call()`? I mean, `shutdownNow()` calls `interrupt()`, which is somehow gets caught inside `call()` and forces the code to immediately break for-loop. So who catches `InterruptedException` and who breaks the loop?

Comment: If a thread is interrupted whilst sleeping, the stack unwinds until something catches the InterruptedException. In the Runnable case, that's in your code. In the Callable case, it's something outside, in code which called the `call()` method.

Comment: @jimmayhem it doesn’t matter who catches the `InterruptedException`, what matters is that it is *not* caught in the loop, unlike your `Runnable` where the `catch` is inside the loop. As this answer says, change the structure from loop(try-catch) to try(loop)catch and you don’t need a `break` statement. And to clarify another point of your question: `shutdownNow()` *immediately* interrupts running tasks, not “as soon as time elapses in `awaitTermination()`”. That method doesn’t care whether you invoke `awaitTermination` at all.